# Yii2 order by 3rd table's value

Tags: mysql, yii2

I'm working with Yii2 and I can't solve it out. I need to OrderBy first table's rows by the third table's column.

First table: user [id, ....]

Second table: info [id, user_id, city_id, ...]

Third table: city [id, title, latitude, longitude]

models/User:

```
public function getInfo()
{
    return $this->hasOne(InfoClear::className(), ['user_id' => 'id']);
}
```

models/Info

```
public function getCity()
{
    return $this->hasOne(City::className(), ['id' => 'city_id']);
}
```

models/RecommendedSearch

```
$query = User::find()->joinWith(['info']);
```

Also I have to connect somehow 'city' table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somthing like this

```
User::find()->joinWith(['info' => function(\yii\db\ActiveQuery $q){
    $q->joinWith('city');
}]);
```

Or try

```
User::find()->with('info.city')->all();
```